# Excel named range not accepting "_rollsroyce"

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, named-ranges

I'm making a dependent drop down list. I've made it using named ranges. All my items and sub-items work without a problem. Except the one item called "Rolls Royce". I have multiple multiple word items with the same syntax that do what they need to do. If I change the words it works fine. Can someone please explain if this is some kind of secretly protected/banned word?

** Still haven't found a solution. I tried other double words and the give me no issue. I found somewhere that "R" is reserved but adding "_R" should solve it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I find that for names etc then the space between words has to be avoided.

I would use "Rolls_Royce" in that case as it reads the same.

Comment: Hi Solar Mike, I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. I tried "Tulip Royce" no issue, "Rolls Tulip" no issue, "Rolls Royce" issue, "Royce Rolls" issue, "Rolls" no issue, "Royce" no issue, "Rroyce" issue, "R-Royce" issue, and a bunch more double words without any issue.

Comment: I have just named a cell "Rolls_Royce" and it references as it should. So try that.

Comment: Still not working. Could you try using it in a dependent drop down list using the indirect function?

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? if it did not work for you then you have to work out why, as it works for me.

Comment: I tried. It's not working. For any other combination of words it's no problem...